# Inconsistent behaviour for SimpleDateFormat for timezone Amsterdam

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat

Yesterday I ran into a problem where the date of birth of a person was changed after it was marshalled with XStream from Date to xml and then unmarshalled to Date again. The following code reproduces the strange behaviour of XStream:

```
System.setProperty("user.timezone", "Europe/Amsterdam");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S z");
String textIn = "1933-09-17 00:00:00.0 CET";
Date date = dateFormat.parse(textIn);
String textOut = dateFormat.format(date);

System.out.println("input : " + textIn);
System.out.println("date  : " + date);
System.out.println("output: " + textOut);
```

The results:

```
input : 1933-09-17 00:00:00.0 CET
date  : Sun Sep 17 00:19:32 CEST 1933
output: 1933-09-17 00:19:32.0 CEST
```

I found out that it happens only for dates before 1940. Which is in a certain way explainable: In the Netherlands in 1940 there was a change from the so called "Amsterdamse Tijd" (GMT+00h19m32s) to European time (GMT+01h00m00s). I cannot explain why the timezone changes to saving time (from CET to CEST).

If I change the timezone to Berlin

```
System.setProperty("user.timezone", "Europe/Berlin");
```

I get the results I expect:

```
input : 1933-09-17 00:00:00.0 CET
date  : Sun Sep 17 00:00:00 CET 1933
output: 1933-09-17 00:00:00.0 CET
```

My server is located in Amsterdam. I will set the timezone of the server to Berlin, to work around the problem.

My question is: Do you think this is a bug in SimpleDateFormat? Or is the code invalid because "1933-09-17 00:00:00.0 CET" is an invalid date for location Amsterdam?

If it is a bug, should and where should this be reported?
If the date input is invalid in in itself, shouldn't the parse method throw an error?

Comment: Bah, dates are ***such a headache.*** I am curious to know the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like germany did not do the CET to CEST transition in 1933, while netherlands did:

- [Germany](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=37&year=1933)
- [Netherlands](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=16&year=1933)

Comment: Thanks! The person is born in AMT timezone, or in NST if daylight saving time is active. Then a few years there was NET and NEST and until now we have CET and CEST. History is never simple. Hopefuly the future will be!